# Help with understanding そんなのは単なる甘えだ?

Tags: translation, japanese-to-english

I actually have a few questions about this exchange, if that's alright. The context is the characters' friends are preparing a party to thank A for all their hard work.

> A: 別に気にしなくていいのにさ　私は好きでやってるだけなんだし
>
> B: あいつらだってそんなことわかってるさ…　わかった上で感謝の気持ちを伝えたいんだろ　言わなくても伝わるはず…　そんなのは単なる甘えだ 言葉や行動にしなきゃ伝わらないこともある

My attempt at it was:

A: They really don't have to worry about it. I just like what I'm doing.

B: They know that... and want to show their appreciation. They should express that even without saying... That's just [????]. Sometimes it may not get through without words and actions.

My questions are thus:

1. Am I correct with 私は好きでやってるだけなんだし, or would it be something like "I'm just doing what I like"?
2. I'm struggling with how to naturally incorporate わかった上 in the phrasing in English without it sounding clunky. Is there a good way to do or would omitting it be a better option?
3. I'm afraid I'm misunderstanding most of B's lines and this is my biggest sticking point: 言わなくても伝わるはず… そんなのは単なる甘えだ. I'm aware 甘え is 'depending upon others', but I'm not sure what B is trying to say.

Comment: Do you know what そんなの is referring to? Think about that and it should be clearer. Regarding 2: It is not just 上, but the 上で that is important. This construction implies that the preceding clause is a condition for the sake of the latter clause. See [here](https://nihongonosensei.net/?p=5947) for more example sentences

Comment: @cats My understanding was そんなの is referring to either the previous line, or the fact their friends felt they should be thanking A in some manner.

Thank you for the link! I think I have a better grasp of that part now.

Comment: そんなの refers to 「言わなくても伝わるはず」, so yes, the previous line. I see someone else has already answered, though, so all good now

Answer (score 3):

甘える is a word for a certain type of human interaction which has no consistent rendering in English. It generally tells that you think or act in a way that you take for granted that someone is generous to or understands you. When of a child or a lover, this is typically translated as "dependent", but it has more ways to translate.

> 言わなくても伝わるはず…　そんなのは単なる甘えだ

It is hard to tell with this much of context what intention it was uttered with, but it literally says that a mindset "they know what you feel without language" is expecting too much capacity of empathy of others.

> 1. *Am I correct with 私は好きでやってるだけなんだし, or would it be something like "I'm just doing what I like"?*

好きで means "out of (= because of) love", so either will do in this case.

> 2. *I'm struggling with how to naturally incorporate わかった上 in the phrasing in English without it sounding clunky. Is there a good way to do or would omitting it be a better option?*

～た上で roughly means "on the basis that —", so here I'd reflect it like "and/but they **still** want..."

Comment: @broken_laptop Thank you so much for the detailed reply addressing each point, especially the first! 

From your explanation I'm thinking the line might be something like B is explaining that it's expecting too much for A to know how they (their friends) feel without them expressing their gratitude in some way. Would you need more context to say if that seems like a reasonable inference?

Comment: @Sol It could be an advice for A, a speculation of what "they" think, or a remark on general truth. If this scene still goes on further, there may be a chance to narrow down.

Comment: It seems more like a general statement to me, and it is part of B's explanation as to why their friends are going to the trouble of explicitly showing their appreciation through words/actions.